# Robot Framework and SeleniumLibrary Simple Example

Tags: selenium, robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Suite Set Up  Start Selenium Server
Suite Tear Down  Stop Selenium Server


*** Test Cases ***
Opening
   Open browser  http://www.bbcnews.com googlechrome
```

I am using above code to run simple robot frame work script with selenium.. What am i doing wrong ?? It is stuck at opening.. but doesn't open anything browser..

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem is that you're using very old technology: the most recent release of SeleniumLibrary is from 2012. You should be using Selenium2Library rather than SeleniumLibrary.

From the SeleniumLibrary project page:

> According to http://seleniumhq.org, the old Remote Controller API is
>   officially deprecated in favor of the new WebDriver API. As a result
>   also SeleniumLibrary is deprecated and no new releases are expected.
>   New users should use the already mentioned Selenium2Library and
>   existing users should start to plan migrating to it.

Here's an example of a working test ([in pipe-separated format](http://boakley.github.io/2014/08/20/why-I-like-pipe-formatted-tests/))

```
*** Variables ***
| ${BROWSER} | chrome

*** Settings ***
| Library | Selenium2Library
| Suite Teardown | Close all browsers

*** Test Cases ***
| Example
| | Open browser | http://bbcnews.com | ${BROWSER}
```

By using a variable for the browser, you can run against any browser by using a command line argument. For example, to run with firefox you can do:

```
pybot --variable BROWSER:firefox myTest.robot
```

Note that drivers for chrome and ie need to be downloaded and installed separately.